# UserCreationForm, hash password and authenticate()

Tags: django, authentication, hash, registration

I am new to Django and i'm trying create simple user registration/login app.
For registration I'm using custom UserCreationForm:

```
def registration(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            messages.info(request, "You've successfully registered")
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm
    return render(request, 'accounts/registration.html', {'form': form})
```

And it works well. But writing login function I faced with difficulties. I've got AttributeError at /accounts/login 'User' object has no attribute 'backend'. It seems that authenticate() returns None object even when login/password correct.

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            userData = form.cleaned_data
            user = authenticate(username=userData['username'],password=userData['password'])
            auth_login(request, user)
            messages.info(request, "You're successfully logged in")
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Invalid username or password')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/login')
    else:
        form = LoginForm() 
    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', {'form': form}
```

I think the point is that password saved in DB in hashed form and that's why userData['password'] not identical to value in db for the same username.

What i the best way to fix this bug?

Trace error

```
Internal Server Error: /accounts/login
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\myproject\djcode\first_venv\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
, line 115, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\myproject\djcode\first_venv\myownproject\accounts\views.py", line 36, in login
    auth_login(request, user)
  File "C:\Python27\myproject\djcode\first_venv\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.
py", line 92, in login
    request.session[BACKEND_SESSION_KEY] = user.backend
  File "C:\Python27\myproject\djcode\first_venv\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py",
line 203, in inner
    return func(self._wrapped, *args)
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'backend'
```

Comment: Could you please show UserCreationForm code, may be save password direct into the database. if you user.set_password(<password value>) then it will django encode password value and then at authentication time it will check it properly.

Comment: I use default UserCreationForm http://docs.nullpobug.com/django/trunk/django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm-class.html and do not change it, so in the forms.py I have  only LoginForm (username/password). May be I should  somehow correct it?

Add trace error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this in your code

```
user = authenticate(username=userData['username'],password=userData['password'])
if user:
    user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
    auth_login(request, user)
else:
    print "invalid login"
```

Comment: Invalid login
[05/Jul/2013 16:51:20] "POST /accounts/login HTTP/1.1" 200 631

Comment: it has nothing to do with hashes as long as you use User.objects.create_user method in your UserCreationForm . can you please post your LoginForm and UserCreationForm .. if you are tired of getting this done then just use this https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/

Comment: class LoginForm(forms.Form):
 username = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
 password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

LoginForm is simple, and default UserCreationForm (like this http://docs.nullpobug.com/django/trunk/django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm-class.html )
Thanks for adviсe, I'm trying to learn work with django by creating basic apps. Otherwise I will never learn it :)

Comment: try to debug where the error is ...  create a user from your django admin and run the login view also put < print user> ..after user=authenticate() .... also check if user is getting created when you use the registration view in django admin ....

Comment: I've try this and...oh, magic it works! But with new users. I didn't change anything in registration view but somehow login work with new users (added from the django admin and from the registration view) and don't work with old.
Thank you!